# class内での「self.変数」と「変数」の違いについて

Tags: python, python3, django

djangoのDetailViewをつかわずその機能が書かれた以下のコードがありました。

```
class TopicTemplateView_InsteadOfDetailView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'thread/detail_topic.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['topic'] = get_object_or_404(Topic, id=self.kwargs.get('pk', ''))

        return context
```

気になったラインが一行あって、

```
    context['topic'] = get_object_or_404(Topic, id=self.kwargs.get('pk', ''))
```

このラインは,selfがついていてなぜセルフが必要なのか、絶対必要なのかと思い、selfなしをプリントしてみたところ、どちらも同じ結果を返しました。
(pkの値を位置を与えたときは、どちらも1が返ってきた。）

```
    print(kwargs.get('pk',''))      # 1 
    print(self.kwargs.get('pk','')) # 1
```

self.kwargs, kwargs ともにdictオブジェクトでした。

クラス内では、変数宣言するときに `self.変数 = 値` としますが、`変数 = 値` とでは何が違うのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

インスタンス変数self.kwargsはsetupメソッドの中で[作成されていて](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.0.5/django/views/generic/base.py#L87)、setupはas_viewメソッドが返す[関数の中で呼ばれます](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.0.5/django/views/generic/base.py#L65)。
アクセスがあると、[dispatch](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.0.5/django/views/generic/base.py#L89)されて、[getattr](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.0.5/django/views/generic/base.py#L94)で探し出されて、[TemplateViewのget](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.0.5/django/views/generic/base.py#L157)が呼び出されます。

TemplateViewのgetは

```py
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

こうです。

ここでget_context_dataが呼び出されて、質問のget_context_dataが実行されるので、その時点でkwargsとself.kwargsはオブジェクトとして等しいものを指していると思います。
（実行して確認はしてません。悪しからず）

私は"self.kwargsとする方が紛らわしい"という感想を持ちました。

Comment: なるほど。最終的に返している値は同じなんだけれども、その値を得る過程が違うということなんですね。確かに、そう考えると、selfつけると煩わしいように感じますね。ソースをもとに説明して下さりありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

https://uxmilk.jp/41600

上記のサイトによると、
クラス変数と、インスタンス変数の違いで
クラス変数はそのクラスですべてに共通する値で、インスタンス変数はそのインスタンスごとに別々の値を持つのが特徴のようです。

Comment: この場合はクラス変数でもインスタンス変数でもない、関数の仮引数や関数をスコープとするローカル変数も混じりうるのでご注意ください。